# MySQL data is caching with google cloud SQL and SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, flask-sqlalchemy, mysql-python, pymysql

This is my first question on stackoverflow, so please correct me if I do something wrong :).

My data from a database hosted at Google Cloud SQL is caching with Flask-SQLAlchemy. When I add a new record and try to get that record it doesn't exist.

I am using a script that adds records and I use one to get records.

I first tried it with SQLite, that worked perfectly. But with MySQL at Google Cloud SQL it doesn't.

Every time I add/change something to the database I use `db.session.commit()`

I use the pymysql module with this: `pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()`
And my connection URI looks like this: `mysql://...`

Edit:
This is what I use to add a new record (my script is for adding jokes):

```py
new_joke = Jokes(joke, user["username"], user["id"], avatar_url, "0")
db.session.add(new_joke)
db.session.commit()
```

And this is what I use to get a record (random):

```py
jokes = Jokes.query.all()
randint = random.randint(0, len(jokes) - 1)
joke = jokes[randint]
```

Comment: Hi @Emma. Thanks for your response! I just edited my post with more code info and added the tags you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer!

By doing `db.session.commit()` before making a query, it refreshes it's cache.

My code now looks like this:

```py
db.session.commit()
jokes = Jokes.query.all()
randint = random.randint(0, len(jokes) - 1)
joke = jokes[randint]
```